# dynamic jProgressbar

Tags: swing

I have a class extending JDialog, it contains a JTextField and a button, a jProgressbar
when user cliks on the button a Jprogress bar(Dynamic) must be visible

Answer (score 0):

Add you JProgressBar to Frame when user clicks on Button and repaint the frame. Your progrss bar will be visible.

In button press event:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
     ..........

     add(progressBar);
     repaint();

     .........
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: jProgressBar1.setVisible(true);
        repaint();
      
       for(int i=0;i<=100;i+=5){
              jProgressBar1.setValue(i);
              jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(false);

              
              try{
                  jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(0, 1, 100, 100);//0, 1, 100, 10
              Thread.sleep(100);
              jProgressBar1.setStringPainted(true);
              
         }catch(Exception e){}
        }
the pboblem is when clicking the button, I can see the progressbar with 100 % with a delay